# Moving files to folders, round robin in Python

Tags: python

I have two list. One is a list of files and the other a list of folders.

```
list1[file1,file2,file3,file4]
list2[folder1,folder2]
```

I want to move:

- file1 to folder1
- file2 to folder2
- file3 to folder1
- file4 to folder2

Comment: I don't think it is the same?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great time to use the `itertools` built in library!

```
import itertools
files = ["file1","file2","file3","file4"]
folders = ["folder1","folder2"]
for file, folder in zip(files, itertools.cycle(folders)):
    print("move {} to {}".format(file, folder))
```

This is only the code for the *round robin*. The moving of files should be pretty easy. Look at the `os` module.

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.